# Mongoid create new Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to write an example app using Ruby on Rails and the Mongoid Mapper.

For some kind of Testing I want to write 1000 Testusers into MongoDB...

With the code bolow Mongoid is not able to write unique uid's. In my ruby console i got the right number for the counter but not for the uid.

Does anybody know what I forgot?

```
class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  def self.create_users
    (1..1000).each do |f|
      user = User.new(uid: f.to_s, first_name: "first_name", last_name: "last_name", e_mail: "e_mail")
      user.save!
      puts f
      puts user.uid
    end
  end

  field :uid, :type => String
  field :first_name, :type => String
  field :last_name, :type => String
  field :e_mail, :type => String
  field :messages, :type => String

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :e_mail
  validates_presence_of :uid, :first_name, :last_name, :e_mail
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid

  has_many :messages
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide the field uid in your models. MongoId add the id field for you and manages the value during the create operation.
Simply remove field :uid, :type => String from model

Comment: yes thanks, but thats definitely not the kind of index i want to use... for example: 4f08d13945a36b20370048bf is the id of the last user i inserted... thanks for your answer, but do you know why this happens??

Comment: What do you mean by "not the kind of index i want to use." ? MongoDb uses the ObjectId type as the "primary key" of its "records", so MongoId uses the same type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own ids you can change the name of the uid field to _id and it should work just fine. However, the default generated mongo _id will make it easier to scale and using it removes one of the more difficult aspects of sharding if you ever need that feature.

If you want to use the ones that are generated by default, they are included automatically unless overridden explicitly (behavior which you have seen) so just remove your custom field and you should be all set.

You can read more about ObjectIds [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs).